# PHP Laravel how to sort by using two tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two MySQL tables in my `Laravel`-application, one called `categories` and the other called `employees`. The structure of the `categories`-table is:

```
id
category
order
```

and the `employees` table also has columns called:

```
id
category
order
```

So, lets say I have `categories` like: Consultants, Programmers and Administration and when I create an Employee in the backend I can assign the new employee to one of these categories. Now in the frontend of my `Laravel`-application I want the Employees displayed by the categories, and also the categories by order they are given. Let's say Consultants has order of 2, Programmers order of 1 and Administration order of 3.

Right now my controller looks like this:

```
use App\Employee;

class EmployeesController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
       $employees = Employee::all()->groupBy('category');

       return view('app.employee.index', compact('employees'));
    }
}
```

and my blade view file:

```
@foreach ($employees as $category => $workers)
  <div class="col text-center mb-6">
    <h2>{{ $category }}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row px-4 px-xl-10">
    @foreach($workers->sortBy('order') as $worker)
      // content of the employee
    @endforeach
 </div>
@endforeach
```

This sorts the employees correctly by simply using the categories of the Employees-table but with this I'm not able to sort by categories like I want to as described above.

So, can someone help me out?

**EDIT**

As an example I want the output look like this:

```
Programmers (since this category has order of 1)
 // employees with category "programmers" here

Consultants (2)
 // employees with category "consultants" here

Administration (3)
 // employees with category "administration" here
```

Comment: Not very clear to me. Can you show an example of input and expected output?

Comment: @vivek_23 check out the updated question :-)

Comment: So the `order` used for sorting `Employees` is from Employee table or `categories` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me you column definitions are a bit confusing, may I suggest a change to your columns:

```
Table 'categories'
------------------
id
name
order

Table 'employees'
-----------------
id
category_id
```

Add a foreign key to the employees table:

```
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')
```

And then your models could be mapped to each other with relationship methods:

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    public function category()
    { 
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function employees()
    { 
        return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
    }
}
```

So with this in place we can simply query the database from the controller by:

```
use App\Category;

class EmployeesController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
       $categories = Category::orderBy('order')->get();

       return view('app.employee.index', compact('categories'));
    }
}
```

and display the results in your blade view:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
  <div class="col text-center mb-6">
    <h2>{{ $category->name }}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row px-4 px-xl-10">
    @foreach($category->employees as $employee)
      // content of the employee
    @endforeach
 </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: oh ok, so when I get this right I got to add a `Category` model too?

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot when using Laravel to also use the built in eloquent support in models for your data querying

Comment: hmm when I try to do `$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')` I get an error: `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails....CONSTRAINT 'employees_category_id_foreign' FOREIGN KEY ('category_id') REFERENCES 'categories' ('id')` :-/

Comment: Thats because youre trying to add a foreign key to a table rhat hasnt been created yet. Change order of migration files or create all your foreign keys in last migration file

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change your query to :

```
$categories = Category::with(['employees'=>function($q){
   $q->orderBy('order');
}])->orderBy('order')->get();
```